# One dimensional pgfplot doesnt display all ticks

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I cannot figure out why I only see the first few ticks but not even the first one when compiled...

```
   \documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
axis y line = middle,
axis x line = none,
ymin = 7000, ymax = 8000,
ytick={7065.77,7066.14,7081,7083.23,7092.96,7100.4,7100.94,7104.89,7105.5,7106,7107.89,7110.7,7110.75,7112.65,7116.38,7120.29,7121.44,7140.67,7151.67,7248.18,7111,7113,7140},
yticklabels={7065.77,7066.14,7081,7083.23,7092.96,7100.4,7100.94,7104.89,7105.5,7106,7107.89,7110.7,7110.75,7112.65,7116.38,7120.29,7121.44,7140.67,7151.67,7248.18,7111,7113,7140}
]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You need to add at least one `\addplot` command to make the given `axis` parameters work, e.g. `\addplot coordinates { (1,7100) };`. (And since at present the values of `ytick` and `yticklabels` are identical, you don't need to provide the latter.)

Comment: the most of your `ytick`s are to close to each other, so label overlap.